# Excel formula to pull data from Column B, if Column A matches Column C when multiple rows will match

Tags: excel-formula

I need some help with a formula to pull data from one sheet in Excel, to a database in another sheet.

The raw data:

[image: 1]

The final database:

[image: 2]

As you can see from the images, the data list I'm searching for is all over the place.

I want to pull it through to the final database, but my formula doesn't account for the fact that there are multiple rows with the values I'm searching for. Not all the listings have all the relevant information either, so the rows between them aren't constant.

I've tried VLOOKUP, MATCH, IF, etc, and the formula in the image is the closest I've come to making it work.

I can pull it through manually, but if there's a formula to make my life easier, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Are you trying to pull the details for one arbitrary business name at a time, or is your goal to transform your entire Sheet2 database into your Sheet1 format?

Comment: The latter. I need all the information in Sheet 2 to pull through to Sheet 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below method is assuming the following

- All the groups contain at least Name
- There is no cell without its header name (any cell without header
  will be ignored).

Insert a column before the header names (a new column A will be created)

Insert the following formula in A2

```
=IF(B2="Name",A1+1,A1)
Insert 0 in A1
```

Drag the formula till the range end

[image]

Now make a table with all your headers and insert the formula in first cell of that table, the formula is an array formula and has to be entered using Ctrl+Shift+Enter

[image]

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$18,MATCH(1,IF(($A$2:$A$18=$E2)*($B$2:$B$18=F$1),0)))
```

You have to change the cell references according to your data

NA means there is no data for that header.

Comment: Thank you so much! The formula worked with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach with some code.

Look what value is in Column A, Sheet 2 and the copy paste it to the Sheet 1.

```
Sub transposeData()

Dim Sht1 As Worksheet
Set Sht1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Name of worksheet 1
Dim Sht2 As Worksheet
Set Sht2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2") 'Name of worksheet 2

Dim lrow1 As Long
Dim lrow2 As Long
Dim i As Long

lrow2 = Sht2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'Find last row for sheet 2, Column A

For i = 1 To lrow2 'Loop from 1st row to last row in sheet 1
lrow1 = Sht1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1 'Find last row in sheet 1
    Select Case Sht2.Cells(i, 1).Value 'Check the current value in Sheet 2, Column A
        Case Is = "Name" 'If the value is "Name" then copy to sheet 1, Column A
            Sht1.Cells(lrow1, 1).Value = Sht2.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Case Is = "Number" 'If the value is "Number" then copy to sheet 1, Column C
            Sht1.Cells(lrow1, 2).Offset(-1, 0).Value = Sht2.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Case Is = "Address" 'If the value is "Address" then copy to sheet 1, Column D
            Sht1.Cells(lrow1, 3).Offset(-1, 0).Value = Sht2.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Case Is = "Email" 'If the value is "Email" then copy to sheet 1, Column B
            Sht1.Cells(lrow1, 4).Offset(-1, 0).Value = Sht2.Cells(i, 2).Value
        Case Is = "Website" 'If the value is "Website" then copy to sheet 1, Column E
            Sht1.Cells(lrow1, 5).Offset(-1, 0).Value = Sht2.Cells(i, 2).Value
    End Select
Next i
End Sub
```